# software centre not signing to ubuntu one

Tags: software-center

I am having trouble signing into ubuntu one from software,it says incorrect email or password. I am able to sign into the website. I have seen similar questions but so far no effective answer.

Comment: Ubuntu One was discontinued years ago http://linuxg.net/starting-with-the-31st-of-july-ubuntu-one-will-be-officially-dead/

Comment: @MarkKirby: No, that's a misconception of the question; please see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug which is said to have been fixed.

https://launchpad.net/bugs/1616943

So hopefully, if you update all packages:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

it will work.